# SQL ORACLE SUM FUNCTION

Tags: sql

HELLO EVERYONE AM HAVING PROBLEM WITH MY CODE IT GIVES ME THREE MULTIPLE OUTPUTS WHILE I NEED ONE ROW WITH THE TOTAL TREES NUMBER AND TOTAL PRICE

--------------MY CODE---------------

- SELECT A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID ,A3_ORDER_ITEM.QUANTITY AS "Number of
  Trees", A3_ORDER_ITEM.QUANTITY*A3_TREE.PRICE AS "PRICE"  FROM
  A3_CUSTOMER INNER JOIN A3_ORDER_FORM ON
  A3_ORDER_FORM.CUSTOMER_ID=A3_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID INNER JOIN
  A3_ORDER_ITEM ON A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID=A3_ORDER_FORM.ORDER_ID INNER
  JOIN A3_TREE ON A3_TREE.ID=A3_ORDER_ITEM.TREE_ID WHERE
  A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID = '00000072';

---------------THE OUTPUT----------------------------
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhIis.png)

Comment: (1) Please use *sentence case* rather than ALL CAPS -- this is really hard to read. (2) Please format and indent your code in the question. (3) [Please do not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) -- copy the output as text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aggregation query:

```
SELECT A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID ,
       sum(A3_ORDER_ITEM.QUANTITY) AS "Number of Trees",  
       Sum(A3_ORDER_ITEM.QUANTITY*A3_TREE.PRICE) AS "PRICE"
  FROM A3_CUSTOMER 
 INNER JOIN A3_ORDER_FORM ON A3_ORDER_FORM.CUSTOMER_ID=A3_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID 
 INNER JOIN A3_ORDER_ITEM ON A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID=A3_ORDER_FORM.ORDER_ID
 INNER JOIN A3_TREE ON A3_TREE.ID=A3_ORDER_ITEM.TREE_ID 
 WHERE A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID = '00000072'
Group by A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID;
```

This query will work for multiple `A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID` also. It will give one record per `A3_ORDER_ITEM.ORDER_ID`

Comment: Just a note, giving answers to questions posted like the above further encourages such quality..

Comment: @costaparas it is the first question by OP. So I helped and I have seen your comment on question. So gave answer to help him considering he will take care of quality as mentioned in your comment on question onwards.